# Windows Application Packaging project with Full Trust Process stays running after closing UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10

I'm using the Desktop Bridge to create a Full-Trust UWP app so I can run cmd commands from my UWP app. I followed this [tutorial](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) and got everything working just fine. However I noticed that when closing the UWP or the trusted process (WinForms app in my case) or both the packaged project keeps running. The debug mode keeps running and I can see the process in my task manager. Is there something extra I have to do to avoid that?

Comment: We can't reproduce this problem, My test sample is `GlobalHotkey`, please tell which sample you have used.

Comment: I'm not using a sample project. I followed the tutorial I linked in the post and files community (https://github.com/files-community/Files)
I was able to track down the source of the issue. The Runtime Component I'm using for bi-directional communication is still running that's why the package process isn't killed.

Comment: The is actually true. It's just in my case the runtime broker stays for around 30 seconds (it seems the reason behind it is to save ram if the app is launched again right after being closed) and I have a Background Task Host which stays up 30 more seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it wasn't actually an issue. The app will stay running for 30 to 60 seconds then exit. I guess it's to save memory in case it gets launched right after closing. Don't quote me on that though.